# How to find in-degree neighbours of node i in graph using networkx Python library

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, graph-theory

I want to find the in-degree neighbours of nodes in the following networkx graph :
[image: Graph]

I want the output to look like : 
inList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,6,0], [1,4,5,0], [2,0]...] 
where inList[0] = in degree neighbours of node 0, ie [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
inList[n] = indegree neighbours of node n

This is the code I have written :

```
inList = [list]*7

for node in g.nodes():
  neighbours = [v for v in g.neighbors(node)] #gives out-degree neighbours of node
  # print(neighbours)
  for i in range(len(neighbours)):
    inList[neighbours[i]] = inList[neighbours[i]].append(node)  #appends the node into inList[neighbour] for that ith iteration
```

but it shows the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-949533b17bca> in <module>()
      8   for i in range(len(neighbours)):
      9     # inDegree.append()
---> 10     inList[neighbours[i]] = inList[neighbours[i]].append(node) 

TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'
```

Any suggestions to this will be highly appreciated!

**ETA** : The code worked with the following changes in first and last line (Thanks @python-user):

```
inList = [[] for i in range(7)]


for node in g.nodes():
  neighbours = [v for v in g.neighbors(node)]
  print(neighbours)
  for i in range(len(neighbours)):
    inList[neighbours[i]].append(node)
```

Comment: you probably meant, `inList = [[] for i in range(7)]`

Comment: I tried this but it showed AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: for debugging purpose i used g.add_edge(edge1,edge2) but the graph will originally be used on any networkx graph